# Jquery Ajax Email Sending File Instead Of Message

Tags: php, html, jquery, post

I have a simple contact form that I want to submit to an email.
Everything is working fine except that instead of the input values being sent in the body of the email it's sending a file.
I tried changing the content-type of my php file but the only thing that changes is the format of the file that's sent, .html or .txt.
It's my first time working with ajax or PHP, so what am I doing wrong here?

I tried inserting the html tags on the message $body and tried without them as well, same thing happens.

Here's my jquery

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                dataType:'html',
                url:"./scripts/email.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:({nome:$("input[name='name']").val(),email:$("input[name='email']").val(),telefone:$("input[name='phone']").val()}),

                beforeSend: function(data){ 

                    }, success:function(data){
                        alert("Dados Enviados");
                    }, complete: function(data){}


                });
            });
```

And here's the PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){


$nome = strip_tags($_POST['nome']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$telefone = strip_tags($_POST['telefone']);

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html: charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "From: mexample@example.com\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: example@example.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\n";
$emailsender = "example@example.com";


$to = "receiver email";
$subject = "Formulario - Contato";
$body = "<html>
            <head>
                <title> Formulario </title>
            </head>
            <body>".
            "<p>". "Nome: " .strip_tags($nome). "</p>".
            "<p>". "Email: " .strip_tags($email). "</p>".
            "<p>"."Telefone: " .strip_tags($telefone). "</p>".
            "</body>
        </html>";


if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers ,"-r".$emailsender)){ 
    $headers .="Return-Path: " . $emailsender . "\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}


}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome. Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude

Comment: check with   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",

Comment: data shpuld be like :  data:{nome:$("input[name='name']").val(),email:$("input[name='email']").val(),telefone:$("input[name='phone']").val()},  no need ()